# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Error web api ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a web api application but I have a problem with my ajax call(using angularjs). My get method is ok but when I want to call `getbyid` method, it returns 405(method not allowed).

Controller:

```
public class BasicInformationRepository : IBasicInformationRepository
{
    private readonly PezhContext _context;

    public BasicInformationRepository(PezhContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// takes all SUBSYSTEMS
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>SUBSYSTEMS</returns>
    public IEnumerable<BasicInformation> GetSubSystems()
    {
        return _context.BasicInformation.Where(a => a.BsiType == 1 && a.BsiParrentId == 0);
    }

    public IEnumerable<BasicInformation> GetSubMenuBySubSystem(int subSystemId)
    {
        return from bsi in _context.BasicInformation
            where (bsi.BsiParrentId == subSystemId && bsi.BsiType == 2)
            select bsi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code shown does not look like a derived `ApiController`. Update the question with [mcve]. also check to make sure that the controller actions are tagged with appropriate http verb attribute

Comment: where is `getbyid`?